# Preparing breaded pork chops

Tags: pork-chops

Is it OK to bread the chops and put them in the frig for a few hours  before frying, or will that just make the breading soggy?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not, it will yield a thick dense crust. You can prepare everything ahead of time, keep it in the fridge separate and then bread everything at the last minute. Since there is only a couple of bowls it will clean up quickly. If you marinate the pork chops put them on a wire rack uncovered in the fridge for  a couple of hours before you bread them. If you absolutely need to bread them ahead of time have some bread crumbs or panko and roll them again right before you fry.

Comment: I do my breading in deep (soup) plates instead of bowls. They are perfectly easy to put away in the dishwasher withoug taking up so much space that it has to be started right away.

Answer (score 1):

I think it'll be fine. All sorts of products are breaded, fried, and frozen, and a few minutes in an oven crisps them right up. If you're going to fry these chops, it won't take long for the hot oil to drive off any water and crisp whatever's left.